# Counting occurrences in a vector

Tags: c++

This program reads strings of numbers from a txt file, converts them to integers, stores them in a vector, and then tries to output them in an organized fashion like so....

If txt file says:

```
7 5 5 7 3 117 5
```

The program outputs:

```
3
5   3
7   2
117
```

so if the number occurs more than once it outputs how many times that happens. Here is the code so far.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int str_to_int(string& s)
{
    stringstream ss(s);
    int num;
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter file name.\n";
    string file;
    cin >> file;
    ifstream f(file.c_str(), ios::in);

    string num;
    vector<int> numbers;
    while(f>>num)
    {
        int number = str_to_int(num);
        numbers.push_back(number);
    }

    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
     if(i = 0 && numbers[i]!= numbers[i+1]) cout << numbers[i] << endl;
     if(i!=0 && numbers[i]!= numbers[i-1])
     {
          cout << numbers[i] << '\t' << counter << endl;
          counter = 0;
     }
     else ++counter;
    }
 }
```

Edit: Program is getting stuck. Looking for an infinite loop right now.

Comment: No it isn't homework. Read profile.

Comment: Your bug is if(i **=** 0). You want to use ==. Single equal sign is assignment.

Comment: Gah, I always do that when I'm dealing with != as well.

Comment: Why was this not closed? He did not even ask a question.

Comment: I asked before, after I received the response I was looking for, I edited it...l2read

Comment: Also, and I mean this in the kindest way possible, learn how to format your code properly (ie. consistently). Pick a style and stick with it, consistent amounts of indentation, and always move the body of a compound statement onto the next line, preferably with the always braces there. People will argue different style rules. It's less important what you choose than that you apply it consistently.

Comment: Changing the question in this manner invalidates the original answers. It's probably best to accept an answer to the original and start a new question for a new problem.

Comment: I've been told about 20 different things regarding whether you should ask a different question or just edit it. I guarantee if I posted a new question I would get tons of "duplicate" responses. If a mod could clarify on what you're supposed to do in that situation that would be great. Also in general when I code I leave one line if statements on the same line, and I bracket statements that are more than one line. If it's really that bad I"ll change it.

Comment: @trikker: That hostility is unnecessary. You ask ten questions a day, so you can understand my confusion - at some point it seems like you are just asking questions for reputation.

Comment: Well it is a programming Q&A site...and I've got questions....sorry if it bothered you?

Comment: @trikker: Sarcasm is also unnecessary. But you editing out your actual question from your post...you can't see why that would lead to my confusion about the purpose of the post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a map, where the key is the number you're tracking and the value is the number of occurrences?

If you must use a vector, you've already got it sorted. So just keep track of the number you previously saw. If it is the same as the current number, increment the counter. Every time the number changes: print out the current number and the count, reset the count, set the last_seen number to the new number.

Comment: Reading backwards instead of reading ahead, of course. I'll post what I implemented, for some reason the program gets stuck. Must be an infinite loop in there somewhere.

Comment: @bstpierre : Is a std::vector sorted by default? @

Comment: No, it is not sorted. OP's code has `sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());`

Answer (score 9):

You could use a map of numbers to counters:

```
typedef map<int,unsigned int> CounterMap;
CounterMap counts;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
{
   CounterMap::iterator it(counts.find(numbers[i]));
   if (it != counts.end()){
      it->second++;
   } else {
      counts[numbers[i]] = 1;
   }
}
```

... then iterate over the map to print results.

EDIT:
As suggested by lazypython: if you have the [TR1 extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) [wikipedia.org] available, unordered_map should have better performance...

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<int,unsigned int> CounterMap;
CounterMap counts;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
{
   CounterMap::iterator it(counts.find(numbers[i]));
   if (it != counts.end()){
      it->second++;
   } else {
      counts[numbers[i]] = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd use a hashmap (or an unordered map, or whatever they call them in the tr1).  You're will have O(nlgn) performance in the number of entries, while a hashmap will have O(nlgn) performance in the number of *keys* of the map, for any large application of this the number of entries will dwarf the number of keys.

Comment: btw, this does not require your vector to be sorted first.

Comment: @lazypython good point. I was just thinking about the base stl release. I don't think a toy program like this will be concerned with speed, but I suppose it's best to learn the right techniques the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Using a map is the **practical** solution. What you should do is to solve this problem :)

This is called frequency counter. So, you have a sorted vector and all what you have to do is to count successive equal numbers. In other words, you have to check each number with its successor.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
{
    size_t count = 1;

    size_t limit = numbers.size() - 1;
    while(i < limit  && numbers[i] == numbers[i+1])
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }

    std::cout << numbers[i] << "\t" << count << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This program reads strings of numbers
>   from a txt file, converts them to
>   integers, **stores them in a vector**, and
>   then tries to output them in an
>   organized fashion like so....*(emphasis added)*

What is the point of this storage step?  If you are reading the numbers from a file, then you already have them in order, ready to be processed (counted) one at time, as you encounter them.

> However, I would need a way for it to know when it sees a new number.

I advise you to have a look at `std::set` or `std::map`.  I expect either of these containers would do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[`Std::count()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/count.html) fits the bill nicely.

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cur = numbers.begin();
std::vector<int>::const_iterator last = numbers.end();
while (cur != last) {
    unsigned cnt = std::count(cur, last, *cur);
    std::cout << *cur;
    if (cnt != 1) {
        std::cout << " " << c;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    int saved = *cur;
    while (*cur == saved) {
        ++cur;
    }
}
```

Of course there are a bunch of other algorithms out there that will do the same job. Play with things like [`std::equal_range()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/equal_range.html) in conjunction with [`std::distance()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/distance.html) will do the job just as nicely.

Answer (score 0):

That was fun:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct IncrementMap
{
    IncrementMap(std::map<int,int>& m): m_map(m)    {}
        void operator()(int val) const
    {
        ++m_map[val];
    }
    std::map<int,int>& m_map;
};
struct SpecialPrint
{
    SpecialPrint(std::ostream& s):  m_str(s)    {}
    void operator()(std::map<int,int>::value_type const& value) const
    {
        m_str << value.first;
        if (value.second != 1)
        {
            m_str << "\t" << value.second;
        }
        m_str << "\n";
    }
    std::ostream&   m_str;
};
int main()
{
    std::fstream        x("Plop");
    std::map<int,int>   data;

    std::for_each(  std::istream_iterator<int>(x),
                     std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                     IncrementMap(data)
                );
    std::for_each(  data.begin(),
                    data.end(),
                    SpecialPrint(std::cout)
                );
}
```