# How does this code count the number of occurrences of each letter C++

Tags: c++, string, adhoc

```
for(int i = 0;i < length; i++){
        count[string[i] - 'a']++;
    }
```

I have seen many people use this code to count the number of occurrences of each letter in a string.Would like to know how this code does that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting occurences in a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204313/counting-occurences-in-a-vector)

Comment: Which part do you don't understand ?

Comment: I don't get the  -'a' part

Comment: You should look up the ASCII table. By `c - 'a'`, you get the distance of `char c`'s value from `'a'`, which is also an index of a letter in the alphabet.

Comment: +LogicStuff Thanks,now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Every char is a number in C++. So count[i] stores the number of occurences of i'th letter.